# Concurrecy In Static Classes

Tags: c#, concurrency, static

Can anyone please suggest me whether this code will cause concurrency or not.

This is a static class used in  forms and and used for some database transactions.

This involves invoking of static function from asp.net pages and passing parameters as ref type.

I am using reference type.

As it is web based,does  it Create some concurrency.
///

Here is code from my sample class.

```
public static class DataClass
{

  static SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(
      ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlserverconnectionstring"]
                                                .ConnectionString);

    public static string  GetCon()

    {

     return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlserverconnectionstring"].ConnectionString;

    }
    public static void Conn(ref SqlConnection con)
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
    }
    public static DataSet GetDataSet(string qry)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(qry, con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds);
        return ds;
    }
    public static bool ExecuteCommand(ref SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        bool i =true;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        Conn(ref con);
        SqlTransaction trans =con.BeginTransaction(); 
        cmd.Transaction = trans;
        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            trans.Commit();
        }
        catch
        {
            trans.Rollback();
            i = false;
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Close(); 
        }
        return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Concurrency most likely isn't the correct word here. Can you rephrase what you are asking?

Comment: i think in concurrent thread if afraid if the values passed to function calls may overlap for simultaneous calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have defined a static SQLConnection, I believe it may cause concurrency issues.

```
static SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlserverconnectionstring"].ConnectionString);
```

If two different objects try to run a query, they will run them on the same instance of sql connection object.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that isn't thread-safe/ However, since SqlClient uses connection-pooling by default, you can just drop the static connection, and have each usage do something like:

```
using(var conn = OpenConnection()) {
    ...//code
}
```

where `OpenConnection` returns a **new** `SqlConnection` each time. This is not the same as a different **underlying** connection each time, and you will usually (in a winform) find a very  low number of connections being used (1 if you get really lucky).

Comment: thanx @MarcGravell, also is there any problem in ExeuteCommand() , it uses parameter in ref form

Comment: @RohitKumar there is absolutely no reason for that `ref`; it achieves nothing useful there. Likewise in `ExecuteCommand`. My apologies if this sounds harsh (that isn't my intent), but: from that code, I conclude that the author doesn't fully understand what `ref` does.